# Auto increment from a custom id in sequelize with feathers-js not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I am trying to create a table that autoincrements starting from 1000.

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54005949/adding-auto-incrementing-integer-with-a-starting-value-in-sequelize), here's my code:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get("sequelizeClient");
  const users = sequelizeClient.define(
    "users",
    {
      first: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        defaultValue: "User",
        //allowNull: true,
      },

    },
    {
      initialAutoIncrement: 1000,
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        },
      },
    }
  );

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  users.associate = function (model) {
    // Define associations here
  };

  return users;
};
```

Where do I correctly place the `initialAutoIncrement: 1000,` option as this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included both mySql and postgres in the tags for your post, so I'm not sure which dialect you are actually using.

If you are using postgres, the initialAutoIncrement option will not work. It's for mySql only.

https://sequelize.org/api/v7/interfaces/modeloptions#initialAutoIncrement

Comment: I am using postgres, thank you for this.

Comment: Link is broken...